# MUI Datagrid: How to add a Checkbox that can be controlled by each row?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I know that the way of adding a Checkbox or TextField is by using renderCell and it works, I can see the Checkboxes:

[image]

However, I don't understand how I'm supposed to then control each row's Checkbox/TextField individually. Like, what if I want row 1 to have a "filled" variant of the TextField and row 2 to have an "outlined" variant.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {DataGrid} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import {Box, Checkbox, TextField} from "@mui/material";

const columns = [
  {field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 30},
  {field: "col1", headerName: "Column 1", width: 150},
  {field: "col2", headerName: "Column 2", width: 150},
  {field: "col3", headerName: "Column 3", width: 150, renderCell: (params) => <Checkbox />},
];

const rows = [
  {id: 1, col1: "Example", col2: "Content", col3: ??????},
  {id: 2, col1: "Example", col2: "Content", col3: ??????},
  {id: 3, col1: "Example", col2: "Content", col3: ??????},
];

export default function Table() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{}}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I tried adding a new `<Checkbox />` with props inside like `<Checkbox defaultChecked/>` but of course, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look for my example for you. Hope I answer your question.
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-leaf-xm32lk?file=/Demo.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRenderCellParams } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Checkbox from "@mui/joy/Checkbox";

function RenderCheckBox(props: GridRenderCellParams<any, boolean>) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(props.value); // Initiated react binded value with param from `rows`

  // Handler for user clicks to set checkbox mark or unset it
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };
  //The bind for dynamic mark/unmark: checked={checked}
  //The handler for user clicks: onChange={handleChange}
  return (
    <Checkbox
      label="some text"
      size="lg"
      checked={checked} 
      onChange={handleChange} 
    />
  );
}

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 30 },
  { field: "col1", headerName: "Column 1", width: 150 },
  { field: "col2", headerName: "Column 2", width: 150 },
  {
    field: "checked",
    headerName: "Column 3",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: RenderCheckBox
  }
];
// Here 'checked' field will pass the param to component.
const rows = [
  { id: 1, col1: "Example", col2: "Content", checked: true },
  { id: 2, col1: "Example", col2: "Content", checked: false },
  { id: 3, col1: "Example", col2: "Content", checked: false }
];

export default function RenderCellGrid() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}
```